# Não consigo inserir os dados na tabela sql com um formulário

Tags: php, html, sql

Estou a editar um plugin em wordpress, e queria com um formulário que fiz que o utilizador ao preencher o formulário e os dados fossem inseridos na base de dados já tenho código mas algo não funciona, poderiam ajudar-me?

Código PHP:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pap";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$instrucao = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tickets(problema, eletrecidade, agua, assunto, info) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
if ($instrucao == FALSE) {
    echo "<p>ERRO: dados não inseridos!</p>";
} else {
    $instrucao->bind_param("sssss", $_POST["problema"], $_POST["eletrecidade"], $_POST["agua"], $_POST["assunto"], $_POST["info"]);
    $resultado = $instrucao->execute();
    if ($resultado == TRUE) {
        echo "<p>Dados inseridos.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>ERRO: dados não inseridos!</p>";
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Codigo HTML:

```
<form name="registodados" method="POST" action="submit.php">
    <fieldset>
        <!-- Escolher problema geral -->
        <label>Problema Geral</label>
        <select name="prob" id="prob">
            <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha uma opção...</option>
            <option  value="luz">Luz</option>
            <option  value="agua">Agua</option>
            <option  value="elevador">Elevador</option>
        </select>

        <!-- Escolher problemas eletrecidade -->
        <label>Eletrecidade</label>
        <select name="eletrecidade" id="eletrecidade">
            <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha uma opção...</option>
            <option  value="curto circuito">Não há luz</option>
            <option  value="curto circuito">Curto circuito</option>
        </select>

        <!--Escolher problemas agua -->
        <label>Agua</label>
        <select name="agua" id="agua">
            <option disabled selected hidden>Escolha uma opção...</option>
            <option value="Nao ha agua">Não há água</option>
            <option value="Inundacao">Inundação</option>
        </select>
        <label for="assunto">Assunto:</label>
        <input type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto" maxlength=100 placeholder="Assunto">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="info">Info:</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="info" id="info" maxlength=50 placeholder="Descrição detalhada"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
        <input type="submit" value="Submeter">
    </div>
</form>
```

E por fim a tabela SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `problema` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `eletrecidade` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `agua` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `assunto` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `info` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Já tentei vários excertos de código encontrados na internet e nada funciona, se me puderem ajudar, é para um projeto na escola já não tenho muito tempo.

Comment: da algum erro? ta indo para pagina da action? ou simplesmente não acontece nada?

Comment: simplesmente nao acontece nada, clico em submit a pagina da refresh e nao aparece nada na base de dados

Comment: tenta assim `<form name="registodados" method="POST" action="submit">` ou assim `<form name="registodados" method="POST" action="./submit">`

Comment: continua a não resultar amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No select está com o name 'pro', mas ao envia por banco de dados está como 'problema'.

Altere de:
`select name="prob" id="prob"` --> `$_POST["problema"]`

Para:
`select name="problema" id="prob"` --> `$_POST["problema"]`

Troca o name para problema ou verifica dando um var_dump($_POST) e ver as informações que estão recebendo e como elas estão passando.

Answer (score 0):

Faz o seguinte.
Faz uma página com o código pra inserção separado, com por exemplo o nome "insert.php"
No formulário, coloca no "action" isso

```html
<form name="registodados" method="POST" action="insert.php">
```

e no button lá no final vc coloca "type='submit'". 

Depois dá notícia pra gente se funcionou.

Comment: Já consegui resolver obrigado!

Comment: Que bom, Daniel!
Ok!